# Documents are not inserting using php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert a document using PHP for my project but the code is not working.

for reference, I have echoed "still here" and "done".

But the code is not able to execute the insert query please help.

I have already tried all the stack overflow and other sites but non of them work properly.

```
<?php

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   include 'lib/JSON.php';

   // connect to mongodb
   $client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

   // select a database
   $db = $client->hm;
   $collection = $db->sc;
   $count = $collection->count();

   $document = array("_id" => $count,
          "device_id" => 100,
          "pin" => 17,
          "status" => "True");  

   echo "still here";
   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "done"
?>
```

I am only getting "still here" on browser.

Comment: That looks like a run-time error in `$collection->insert()`.  You'll have to get into that file to find the error.  Be sure you have error reporting turned on.

Comment: How to turn error reporting on??

Comment: I turned on error reporting but no error is being displayed @TimMorton

Comment: sometimes runtime errors don't display anything when error reporting is turned on in the script.  You might surround the method call in a try catch block to see what it reports.  Other than that, I don't know anything about mongoDB...  You'll have to check their documentation.  good luck!

Comment: I have tried it with try-catch too but didn't work. anyways I will figure something else !! thank you @TimMorton

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method `insertOne`. Does that give some additional errors?

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-insertOne/